# Suppose $R$ is a division ring and $b$ is a nonzero element of $R$. Prove that if $bb = b$, then $b = 1_R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I started with let $bx = 1_R$ and then $bv = b^2v$. A division ring has identity but does not have to be commutative. How should I proceed?

Comment: Is $a$ supposed to be involved in your question?

Comment: No sorry going to edit.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $b\neq 0$ and $b \in R$ a division ring implies that $b^{-1} \in R$

Answer (score 3):

$bb=b$ that implies $b(b-1)=0$ and every divisoin ring has no zero divisors Thus we have since $b\ne0$ $b-1=0$ that is $b=1.$

Comment: I think that works too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $a$ plays no role in your question. Now, since $b$ is not zero it has an inverse. What happens when you multiply the equation $bb=b$ by the inverse of $b$?

Comment: I see, I get b = 1$_R$. I just need to note that b inverse has an inverse. I needed to use property of division ring. So the hint bv = b$^2$v wasn't really useful?

Comment: correct you are.